# Data Access Application Block 4.1 and Transactions

Tags: transactions, enterprise-library, daab

Can anyone please tell me what is the prefered way to manage transaction when using Enterprise Library's DAAB (version 4.1)? I was thinking about

```
Database NewDb = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DBCommand NewCmd = NewDb.GetStoredProcCommand("SProcName");

/* Add parameters here. */

using (TransactionScope NewTrans = new TransactionScope())
{
    NewDb.ExecuteNonQuery(NewCmd);
    NewTrans.Complete()
}
```

but I don't know if I will be doing the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TransactionScope is the preferred way to do transactional work in Enterprise Library. Your example is fine.

You do have the option to do manual transaction management - that's primarily in there for backwards compatibilty for older Entlib code.